# Looking for a word to describe a change in your perception of someone

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a name for the concept of a person's perception in your mind changing based on new information? I'm thinking something like 'taint', but more specific to people and maybe less negative.

For example, I love the music of Chick Corea, but recently learned he is devoted to his belief in Scientology. Try as I might, I cannot even hear his name without thinking about Scientology. Regardless of my thoughts on the religion, my idea of him has changed permanently based on this new information. Does this transformation have a name?

Comment: You’ve had cause to ***reevaluate***

Comment: What you're experiencing is [cognitive dissonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_dissonance).  You are still in the mode of dealing with that dissonance, which is the confusion you feel.  How you eventually deal with it (there are 3-4 main strategies) will determine your feelings in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use the verb **colour/color** here.

From [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/colour) (verb, 3rd sense):

> *[with object]* **Influence, especially in a negative way; distort:**
>
> *‘the experiences had coloured her whole existence’*
>
> *‘My experience of what I read here is also coloured by knowing several contributors.’*
>
> *‘I don't mention it often, because I don't want it to colour the way people read everything I write, or change the way that people talk to me, which it often can.’*

It's less negative than `taint`.

You could say something like: "Learning about his beliefs colored my opinion of him."

Answer (score 4):

So, after you learned about Chick Corea's devotion to scientology, you [**saw [him] in a new light**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/see+in+a+new+light). Alternatively, you ***saw a different side of*** him. I could not find a definition for this idiom, but it refers to seeing (or becoming aware of) aspects of a person's personality you were previously unaware of, and can be used positively or negatively.

Comment: That is a good phrase, but it does not necessarily refer to a change in perception so much as new information being presented.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could say that what you learned about the person caused you to have **second thoughts** or **gave you pause**.

OD

> [**second
>   thoughts**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/second_thoughts):
>   a change of opinion or resolve reached after considering something
>   again
>
> [**give pause to someone (or give someone pause for
>   thought)**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pause): to cause someone to think carefully or hesitate before
>   doing something [such as continuing to think the same way about someone]

Answer (score 0):

It's an ***eye-opener***.

M-W:

> **[eye–opener](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eye%E2%80%93opener)**
>   *noun*
>
> **2 :**  **something** startling, surprising, or **enlightening** : *her biography is a real eye–opener*

Cambridge:

> **[eye-opener](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/eye-opener)**
>   *noun*
>   something that surprises you and teaches you new facts about life, people, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You were **disillusioned**. Been looking for this word just now and I came across this post. I think disillusion is the word we were both looking for.

Comment: Can you add a definition? For what it's worth, I agree that this is one of the right words. But answers on this site are generally required to have sources :)